# OWIN SignIn authenticating after refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm trying to sign in a user with something like....

```
        var accessor = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        var result = await accessor.CreateUserIdentityAsync(new User() { ... });

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
            new AuthenticationProperties { AllowRefresh = false, IsPersistent = false },
            result);
```

and the SignIn works, but if I refresh the page, the user is still authenticated, where I would expect the user to be logged out, since I set both `AllowRefresh` and `IsPersistent` to false. Am I missing something obvious? Or maybe something not-obvious? (If it makes a difference, the 'user' signed in does not actually exist, it's sort of an anonymous authenticated user).

Comment: When you refresh maybe it just reads from cache? Try Ctrl+F5 (refresh without cache).

Comment: Nope, it only works if I delete the cookie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AllowRefresh is a setting that allows/disallows the cookie being refreshed (eg expiry updated) when you request.

It has nothing to do with whether you should still be authenticated if the page is refreshed.

```
bool? allowRefresh = authenticationTicket.Properties.AllowRefresh;
if (issuedUtc.HasValue && expiresUtc.HasValue && base.Options.SlidingExpiration && (!allowRefresh.HasValue || allowRefresh.Value))
{
    TimeSpan t = utcNow.Subtract(issuedUtc.Value);
    TimeSpan t2 = expiresUtc.Value.Subtract(utcNow);
    if (t2 < t)
    {
        this._shouldRenew = true;
        this._renewIssuedUtc = utcNow;
        TimeSpan timeSpan = expiresUtc.Value.Subtract(issuedUtc.Value);
        this._renewExpiresUtc = utcNow.Add(timeSpan);
    }
}
```